# .NET - How can I convert a Task<> to Task (with no type parameter)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, f#, task

`Task<T>` is a separate class from `Task` (no type parameter), and there are some functions that only accept untyped Task as a parameter. **How can I convert a `Task<T>` to a `Task` (with no type parameter)?**

Examples in F#, but same principle applies to C#.

This F# function:

```
let getTask() = task {
    return ()
}
```

creates a `Task<unit>`.

Comment: `public class Task<TResult> : System.Threading.Tasks.Task` so "Task<T> is a separate class from Task" is kind of a strange statement, especially claiming that there are many places where Task<T> is not treated as Task... Some examples may be helpful for future readers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think if the OP knew about the type hierarchy, this question wouldn’t have been asked, as then I’m sure he new a simple cast had sufficed ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just cast:

```
let t = getTask() :> Task
```

Conversely, in case you'd need a `Task<unit>` from any `Task` or `Task<'T>`, F#+ [`Task.ignore` function](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/reference/fsharpplus-task.html#ignore) is helpful, or you could write your own:

```
let asUnitTask t = task { let! _ = t; return () }
```

Comment: C# equivalent: `var untypedTask = task as Task;`

Answer (score -2):

One way is to use the `ContinueWith()` method of `Task<T>`.

C# example: `var untypedTask = task.ContinueWith(t => { });`

F# example: `let untypedTask = task.ContinueWith(Action<Task<unit>>(ignore))`